how to check all keys delegation , target,snapshot keys expiry date of harbor registry repos
I have self hosted harbor registry, want to know the expiry date of all the registry related keys.
On the repos, delegations keys are added and signer are added by the root key.

.docker/trust/tuf/qaregistry/*****/metadata/targets.json
I want to know the expiry of this for all the repos.
